# can you deploy `appsettings.json` to azure function in python (v2 programming model)?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-python-sdk

Can you create and use `appsettings.json` in the repo of an Azure Function in Python (v2 programming model), and so that when you deploy this function the settings end-up in App Settings in the Azure Portal? How to do this?

I thought such method is mentioned in the documentation for [other languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings) and I tried it for Python function but it did not work. I am looking for some pragmatic way to version-control and easily deploy app settings (other than using "advanced edit" functionality in the portal).

Answer (score 1):

The app settings in `appsettings.json` will not be automatically deployed to App Settings in the Azure Portal. Instead, you can use Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell to deploy the app settings to App Settings.

I have tried with the same approach that you provided in the above [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings) in python.

Firstly added [new application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) in azure portal and setup `name`  and `value`.

[image]

Created an `appsettings.json` file in the root directory of the function app.

[image]

Then updated `__init.py__`  as below.

```
import configparser
import os

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('appsettings.json')

my_setting = os.environ["MySetting"]
connection_string = os.environ["ConnectionString"]
```

Then, Iam unable to run the function with following error below.

[image]

I have checked `mysetting` in environmental variable but, no luck.

Try the below one in your environment.

- Add your settings to the App Configuration store. Install the Azure App Configuration Python library by running `pip install azure-appconfiguration`.

[image]

- Set an environment variable named `AZURE_APPCONFIG_CONNECTION_STRING` with the connection string of your App Configuration store.

```
from azure.appconfiguration import AzureAppConfigurationClient
from azure.functions import _app_name

connection_string = os.environ.get("AZURE_APPCONFIG_CONNECTION_STRING")
app_config_client = AzureAppConfigurationClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    setting = app_config_client.get_configuration_setting(key="setting_key")
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Setting value: {setting.value}")
```

Check for further [reference](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-python-provider.md) that may help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I know I'm kinda late to this but I stumbled upon this when I wanted to accomplish the same thing. Tracking appsettings as part of a repo and automatically applying them to your App is now one of the features of https://github.com/luis261/aztraphile which might suit you perfectly since you mention you're working with the V2 programming model in Python (which is exactly what aztraphile is made for/ships with)

If you don't want/need the additional automation features, you could just copy this line from the contained pipelines file: https://github.com/luis261/aztraphile/blob/5de5da9300b27eedc01dede66c1d80a180303320/cfg/azure-pipelines.yml#L61C144-L61C144

```
az functionapp config appsettings set -g '$(ResourceGroupName)' -n '$(FunctionAppName)' --settings '@$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/appsettings.json'
```